# unauthorized_client error when trying to impersonate an account

Tags: python, google-api, authorization, google-api-python-client, google-my-business-api

On Google Business Profile API (Google MyBusiness), I am getting following error when I try to impersonate with an email address:

```
('unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.', {'error': 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description': 'Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.'})
```

I am trying to achieve this using a Python script which is using Google API Client Library:

```
file_location = '/some/folder/file.json'
impersonated_email = 'abc@abc.com'
scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage"]

credentials = ServiceCredentials.from_service_account_file(file_location, scopes=scope, subject=impersonated_email)
```

If I try to access the endpoint without using the `subject` parameter, it is working. But of course the main purpose here is impersonating. And [the Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) says it is possible to impersonate with the `subject` parameter (or via `with_subject` function).

By the way, if I tried some invalid mail address, my error is changing to: `('invalid_grant: Invalid email or User ID', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid email or User ID'})`

So I assume that I can get the user credentials; but have no idea what could have been wrong.

Does anybody have any idea about the issue? What could be the possible issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Google [explains](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#error-codes) that JWT error code like that:

**`error` field**: unauthorized_client

**`error_description` field**: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.

**Meaning**:

> A service account was authorized using the client email address rather than the client ID (numeric) in the Admin console.

**How to resolve**:

> In the Domain-wide delegation page in the Admin console, remove the client, and re-add it with the numeric ID.

I tried that but I still got the error.

Then, after some digging; I saw that you only can impersonate G-Suite accounts.

So, after that I tried same code with another real-person mail which is a G-Suite account and it worked.